# Lex is not returning what I want

Tags: c++, yacc, lex

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
int n_chars = 0;
int n_lines = 0;
%}


%%

"if"|"else"|"while"|"do"|"switch"|"case" {
    printf("Keyword");
}
[a-zA-Z][a-z|0-9]* {printf("Identifier");}
[0-9]* {printf("Number");}
"!"|"@"|"*"|"&"|"^"|"%"|"$"|"#" {printf("Special Character");}

\n      { ++n_lines, ++n_chars; }
.       ++n_chars;

%%

int yywrap() {
    return 1;
}

main(int argc[], char *argv[]) {
    yyin = fopen("index.txt", "r");
    printf("Number of characters is: %d", n_chars);
    yylex();
    return 0;
}
```

My code above returns: **Number of characters is: 0**

The content of my file `index.txt` is:

*if hello #*

*while 1*

*do test*

Why does it return `0`? What I expect is the number of all characters and also it should tell me if it is a `keyword`, an `identifier` or a `special character`.

I must be doing something wrong, since I am very new to this. 
I am using EditPlus. So any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what happends when you  swap these lines **printf("Number of characters is: %d", n_chars);
    yylex();**

Comment: @138 it returns nothing. Not even `Number of characters is: 0`.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two problems with your code.

- You print `n_chars` before calling `yylex`.
- The last rule for `.` will not be matched for anything that is matches by one of the rules above, so you will not get the number of chars with this approach.

With calling `yylex` first, I get the number of "other" characters, such as spaces and newlines.

To count all characters, you can

- Add the statement `n_chars += strlen (yytext);` to the first four rules to count the characters that were matched by the rule.
- Add the statement `REJECT` to the first four rules to continue searching and therefor match the`.` with the action `++n_chars;`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did exactly what you said but now it returns nothing. So how could I get the number of all chars?

Comment: What does "but now it returns nothing" mean?

Comment: There is no output in the console. Only if I type something, it returns something. For instance, if I type `test`, it outputs `Identifier`.

Comment: @reza: you should check the return value of `fopen`. Your symptom suggests that `fopen` returned `NULL` but there is no reason to have to guess; you should *always* check for error returns.

Comment: @ralf: `. ++n_chars;` is totally legal, even for AT&T lex. It's possibly not the best style but it's not an error.